# SSRS trim trailing 0's from double

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, trim, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a calculated field that returns a double "2.000" how can I format this to get rid of unneeded 0's? So that the following occurs:

- When  --> Returns
- 2.000 --> 2
- 2.500 --> 2.5
- 2.510 --> 2.51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it into a double.

```
CBdl(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Text box properties >> Format enter

```
#.####
```

This will display as you require.